# Problems with Android MediaPlayer

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, media

I am making sound application in Android and when I click on button it play sound, it's working good but I have a little problem that I can't solve.
When I click on 1 button it play sound, but when I click on second button it also play sound simultaneously and both sounds are played at the same time.
How can I prevent this? To play only 1 sound at a time.
So I want it to when clicked on 1st button, start playing, when clicked on 2nd button stop sound on 1st button and start playing sound on 2nd button and so on

```
     final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kalas);
  ImageButton sound1=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sound1);
  sound1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.pause();
            mp.seekTo(0);
        }
        else {
            mp.start();   
        }
    }
});

  //HEKLER
  final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hekler);
  ImageButton sound2=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.sound2);
  sound2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(mp2.isPlaying())
        {
mp2.pause();
mp2.seekTo(0);
        }
        else {
            mp2.start();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kalas);
    final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hekler);

    ImageButton sound1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sound1);
    sound1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (mp2.isPlaying()) {
                mp2.pause(); 
                mp.start();
            } else {
                mp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    ImageButton sound2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sound2);
    sound2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.pause();
                mp.seekTo(0);
                mp2.start();
            } else {
                mp2.start();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This worked! But I can't figure it out how it would be for 3rd, 4th button?

Comment: private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private boolean isPlaying;
....
onClick(View v) {
if(isPlaying){
mediaPlayer.stop();
isPlaying=false;}
else {
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.blabla);
mediaPlayer.start();
isPlaying=true;
}

Answer (score 0):

Check if one MediaPlayer is playing, and if so pause that one.

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kalas);
ImageButton sound1=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sound1);
sound1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.pause();
        mp.seekTo(0);
    }
    else {
        if(mp2.isPlaying())
        {
            mp2.pause();
        }
        mp.start();   
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

pause first mediaplayer in click of second button if it is playing

```
if(mp!=null&&mp.isPlaying())
{
  mp.Pause();
  mp2.Start();
}else
   mp2.Start();
```